# SUM query in multiple table with group by sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, select, group-by, sum

Hello friends i have three tables **property_master** , **rent_master**,**expense_master** and fields are as below

property_master --> p_id, p_name

rent_master --> r_id,p_id,r_amount

expense_master --> e_id,p_id,e_amount

i want to total sum of r_amount, and e_amount with single query so my query is as below

```
   SELECT p.p_id AS "Product Code",
   p.p_name AS "Description", 
   SUM(CASE WHEN ri.r_amount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ri.r_amount END) AS "Quantity" ,
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.e_amount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE d.e_amount END) AS "DQuantity" 
   FROM property_master AS p
   LEFT JOIN rent_master AS ri ON ri.p_id = p.p_id
   LEFT  JOIN expense_master AS d ON d.p_id = p.p_id
   GROUP BY p.p_id
   ORDER BY SUM(ri.r_amount) DESC,
   SUM(d.e_amount) DESC
```

When i run above code it will give right value for **r_amount** but for **e_amount** it will give double value for that so any idea how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are two different `rent_master` rows with the same `p_id` values, you get two joined rows for each matching `expense_master` row.

You have to compute the sums with independent subqueries:

```
SELECT p_id AS "Product Code",
       p_name AS "Description",
       (SELECT SUM(r_amount)
        FROM rent_master
        WHERE p_id = property_master.p_id
       ) AS "Quantity",
       (SELECT SUM(e_amount)
        FROM expense_master
        WHERE p_id = property_master.p_id
       ) AS "DQuantity"
FROM property_master
ORDER BY Quantity DESC,
         DQuantity DESC
```